# HTML+CSS Table Alignment [Dynamically]

Tags: html, css

Problem screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

How to align the right column of the table to be all aligned especially the *Student NRIC*.  row and *School's*.

```
    .formstyled {
    width:70%;
    margin-left:5%;
    }

    .formstyled input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea,select {
    width:100%;
    padding-left:3px;

    border: 2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius: 5px;

    }

    .formstyled select {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;

    background: url('arrow.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:98% -1px;
    background-color:white;
    }

    .formstyled input[type=text]:focus,input[type=password]:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #b2d9f9;
   }

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align:center;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:smaller;
    opacity:0.4;
    color: #999;
}

   .formstyled input[type=submit],input[type=reset] {
    width:65px;
    height:25px;

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(149,149,149,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 32%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 40%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 48%,rgba(78,78,78,1) 77%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* W3C */   

    border:none;
    border-top:1px #219fe8 solid;
    border-bottom:2px #219FE8 solid;
    border-radius:15px;

    cursor:pointer;

    color:#F6F6E8;
    font-family:Raleway;
    font-size:smaller;
    letter-spacing:1px;
   }
```

Besides that, any idea on how to decorate the table for my assignment? :\ kind of lost of ideas.. Well, sorta.

Comment: Not clear what you want.Need some html code.Post your code at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/XCt3m/** There :\ I want to have the same alignment for the right column of the table (all the inputs and select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a 4 column layout for this.

The problem is in your **Student NRIC** and **School** rows, not fully taking up the space in the table column, correct?

1st column is your field names.

2nd column (INPUT and SELECT tags) should have column span of 3 except for Student NRIC. Student NRIC should have a tag for each INPUT. Define widths for these 3 tags.

Lastly, create CSS that matches your INPUT and SELECT tags to make their width 100%.

Sample code as a basic illustration/prototype (http://jsfiddle.net/PDVj9/):

```
    <style>
    INPUT, SELECT {
      width:100%;
    }
    .field-title {
      width:100px;
    }
    </style>

    <table style="width:500px;">
    <tr>
    <td class="field-title">
        Student Name
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <input name="student_name" />
    </td>
    </tr>
        <td class="field-title">
            Student NRIC
        </td>
        <td style="width:200px">
            <input name="student_nric_1" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:50px;">
            <input name="student_nric_2" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:150px;">
            <input name="student_nric_3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Wow ! I never thought of colspan like seriously. But look at the "select", it is like still missing 1 pixel on the right side .. I checked it quite a few times but still rather the same

Comment: Could you post that code to JSFiddle? Maybe 1px of padding-right on the select will fix it.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/XCt3m here | Tried padding-right btw but still the same

Comment: Hmmm, a width of 104% on the SELECT seems hacky but does the trick. There seems to be some other styles in play that might be tweaked to get it working right.

Comment: used 101% and solved it with trick but the problem still remain unknown. Another problem I'm facing is after the Student's NRIC colspanned="3", how to adjust the space between that 3 input?

Comment: Adjust space by putting padding on the TD while inversely decreasing the width of the TD.

Comment: Thanks! You have been really helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks! I definitely try.